# Angular - curl API - send 2 parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, jhipster, crud

I have a Jhipster generated app that has an Angular frontend.

I am trying to create a custom curl API. When the user is pressing a button, I want to send to the backend 2 parameters (a string and a number). In the backend I am planning to create another entity based on this  data, but I don't want to send anything back to the frontend.

Should I wrap the string and the number into a Tuple or maybe I should create a custom model class ? What method should I use : Get, Post, Put or Delete ?

So far, I wrote this function in my service class:

```
sendData(userLogin: string , anotherID: number):  void  {
   this.http.put(this.resourceUrl, userLogin, anotherID, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

It is called when the user presses the button. But it seems I cannot send both parameters (`userLogin` and `anotherID`): `Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 4` by using either post or put. The other options are get and delete, but I cannot figure out how to put 2 parameters in the url.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular's HTTP client has defined parameters you can send it for a POST and PUT.

Argument 2 of 3 is the data portion of the request. Argument 3 is the HTTP options for the request.

So your request should look something like this (assumption is you haven't change any options and are using content-type/json).

```
sendData(userLogin: string , anotherID: number):  void  {
   this.http.put(this.resourceUrl, {userLogin, anotherID}, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

[Angular HTTP Client](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request)